# MySQL Entity Framework Trailing Whitespace

Tags: c#, mysql, string, entity-framework, whitespace

Afternoon SA,

I've got a bit of an issue. Actually it's more of an inconvenience than a bug.

We are currently using MS Entity Framework with MySQL for VS2012 (available here [MySQL for Visual Studio](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/visualstudio/)). The problem is that when we perform an insert using EF, it adds trailing whitespace characters to any entry less than the field size.

So if we insert "test1" into a field that is varchar(10), we end up with 5 whitespaces added to the end. Then when we try to query this in other software, we end up not being able to find "test1" because it has 5 extra whitespace characters.

Changing the software that uses this is impossible, otherwise it would be incredibly easy to just fix and trim the result. Is there any way to force EF with MySQL to only insert "test1" without the whitespace? Or will I have to run a manual trim query every time someone inserts into the MySQL database?

Thanks,
E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I've discovered where I was going wrong.

It wasn't the MySQL database after all, it was due to another one of our databases (where "test1" would be found) having Fixed Length set to true in our entity model.

In order to resolve this I changed the original database data type from nchar to nvarchar, and regenerated our model. I also checked that the Fixed Length attribute was set to false as well.

Thanks for anyone who read this, I hope it helps some poor soul later on.

Thanks!